# single click with AgGrid and CellRenderer + CellEditor

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have created a form using AgGrid, the goal of the task is to have form validation for front end only, where first 3 fields are mandatory and next 3 fields are optional.

I have done this task using CellRenderer - to perform an check if field is empty or not and add an error message if it is empty, and CellEditor - basically it is the input and adds a property that sets dirty status on false displaying the error message.

Screen shot of the app below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKXZ0.png)

i want to enhance it to operate using single click, as currently user needs to click twice in order to start populating the field, I have the singleClickEdit: true but it is not working, any ideas?

replicated the issue on a codeSandbox snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-dew-s4n8cm?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: hi i created this codeSandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-dew-s4n8cm?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's happening in this example is that you have `singleClickEdit=true` on a column that also has a custom cell editor.

As it's a custom component, it is up to you to focus on the input element when it is rendered.

A simple way to do this is to give an id to the input:

```
<input
  #input
  [ngClass]="{ 'invalid': !valid }"
  [(ngModel)]="cellValue"
  (ngModelChange)="handleValueChange()"
  (focus)="makeDirty()"
/>
```

Then implement the Cell Editor Event `afterGuiAttached` to focus on the input:

```
export class ValidateInputEditorComponent extends ValidateInputCell
  implements ICellEditorAngularComp {

  @ViewChild("input") input;

  afterGuiAttached() {
    this.input.nativeElement.focus();
  }

  // ...
}
```

See this implemented in the [following sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-pine-hvdol9?file=/src/app/validate-input-editor/validate-input-editor.component.ts).